# htaccess HTTPS only no redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to block port 80 (HTTP) completely and only allow HTTPS requests. I have found many examples of how to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS but I would prefer to display an error instead. I cannot block port 80 in my config file as my hosting provider does not allow me to modify these files. If possible, how can I achieve the same results with htaccess.

The reason for me wanting this on my api.domain.com is for added security after reading this [article](http://swaggadocio.com/post/48223179207/why-the-hell-does-your-api-still-use-http-basic).

Quote from article...

> Aside from abandoning HTTP Basic altogether there is an easy fix. close port 80 on your API host. This stops a connection being made dead in its tracks, preventing any credentials being sent in the clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/error\.php
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/error.php [L,R]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking for however I would prefer to display the error over http not https, another condition is needed.

Comment: @itsliamoco Jon Lin's solution is perfect. Sorry my response was little late :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/error\.php
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}/error.php [L,R]
```

**OR**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/error\.php
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/error.php [L,R]
```

This will check if server port is `80` It will redirect all requests to error.php

Comment: Can you please try now. Fixed the typo

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking for however I would prefer to display the error over http not https, another condition is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Apache httpd has a special directive for this, [SSLRequireSSL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequiressl), which gives a 403 error otherwise. (You could use [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) if you want a better error message and don't otherwise need 403.)