# How to redirect index.php to HTTPS only?

Tags: php, .htaccess, https

This question has been asked many times, but I've tried a lot of different variations with no success - here are examples of what I've tried and what I get:

```
Gives 500 Internal Server Error:
<Location /index.php>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</Location>

Gives TOO MANY REDIRECTS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Gives TOO MANY REDIRECTS
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://foo.bar [L,R=301]

Gives TOO MANY REDIRECTS
<?php
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
?>
```

I haven't been able to get the HTTPS redirect working using any of these methods.

I'm trying to force only index.php to redirect to HTTPS only when users visit

http://foo.bar (including with trailing slash)

http://foo.bar/index.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess HTTPS only no redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949692/htaccess-https-only-no-redirect)

Comment: How is SSL managed? Do you have a certificate installed directly on your server, or are you using some kind of front end proxy? Your last two results imply the later.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest implementing this PHP code in the top of each file:

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "off"){
    $redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    exit();
}
```

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
>   permanent URL redirection, meaning current links or records using the
>   URL that the response is received for should be updated. The new URL
>   should be provided in the Location field included with the response.
>   The 301 redirect is considered a best practice for upgrading users
>   from HTTP to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: This still gives TOO MANY REDIRECTS

Comment: Does index.php have any code that is doing redirects? It sounds like there is a redirect looping issue.

Answer (score 0):

500 Internal server is due to the **Location** directive you are using in htaccess. Location directive used only in server config contaxt.
To redirect index.php to https, you can use use the following rule. I am assuming you are on apache version 2.4 or higher.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} http$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://example.com [L,R]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this rule.

For lower versions of apache, you can replace the Condition line with one of the following :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,NC]
```

It works with:
`http://foo.bar` -> `https://foo.bar`
and  `http://foo.bar/index.php` -> `https://foo.bar`
but not with `http://foo.bar/other`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am Facing same problem on my website my website in Joomla 3.5 
  I am using below code. it works properly in my Joomla! 3.5.1.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.ac.in/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.ac.in/$1 [L,R=301]
```